# Dropdowns blank when rendered as partial view

Tags: .net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to load a modal create form via the method `OnGetCertificationPartial`. The form is loading, however the dropdowns are blank.
[image: Blank Dropdown]

The dropdowns are not blank when loading the /Create page via the `OnGet` method
[image]

How can I get the dropdowns to populate when loaded as a partial via `OnGetCertificationPartial` method?

Create.cshtml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using EmployeeCertification.Models.Scaffold;
namespace EmployeeCertification.Pages.CertificationRuleCertifications
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly EmployeeCertification.Models.Scaffold.EmployeeCertificationDBContext _context;

        public CreateModel(EmployeeCertification.Models.Scaffold.EmployeeCertificationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet(string ruleName)
        {
            ViewData["CertificationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Certifications, "CertificationId", "CertificationName");
        ViewData["CertificationRuleId"] = new SelectList(_context.CertificationRules.Where(i => i.RuleName == ruleName), "CertificationRuleId", "RuleName");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public CertificationRuleCertification CertificationRuleCertification { get; set; }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetCertificationPartial()
        {
            ViewData["CertificationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Certifications, "CertificationId", "CertificationName");
            ViewData["CertificationRuleId"] = new SelectList(_context.CertificationRules, "CertificationRuleId", "RuleName");
            return Partial("/Pages/Shared/_CertificationRuleCertification.cshtml");
        }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.CertificationRuleCertifications.Add(CertificationRuleCertification);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Details.cshtml (the screen the user clicks on to trigger the modal)

```
@page
@model EmployeeCertification.Pages.CertificationRules.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>CertificationRule</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CertificationRule.RuleName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CertificationRule.RuleName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CertificationRule.AppliesToAllEmployees)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CertificationRule.AppliesToAllEmployees)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CertificationRule.Active)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CertificationRule.Active.ActiveName)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.CertificationRule.CertificationRuleId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark details" data-id="@Model.CertificationRule.CertificationRuleId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-modal">Details</button>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="details-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Product Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('button.details').on('click', function () {
                $('.modal-body').load('/certificationrulecertifications/create?handler=CertificationPartial');
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

_CertificationRuleCertification.cshtml (routed to via `OnGetCertificationPartial`)

```
@model EmployeeCertification.Pages.CertificationRuleCertifications.CreateModel
<h1>Add</h1>

<h4>Certification</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationRuleId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationRuleId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CertificationRuleId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CertificationId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create.cshtml (routed to via `OnGet`)

```
@page
@model EmployeeCertification.Pages.CertificationRuleCertifications.CreateModel

<h4>CertificationRuleCertification</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationRuleId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationRuleId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CertificationRuleId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CertificationRuleCertification.CertificationId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CertificationId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: The comment requesting more details needs more detail. What specifically have I left out? I've given the use case with screenshots as well as all the code involved with an explanation.

Comment: It would be nice if you show the code that is working,  to let users to compare.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I added Create.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have a bug. `SelectList` constructor needs an `IEnumerable` list as a parameter, but you use `IQueryable`. And create model too. You can try this

```
CertificationRuleCertification= new CertificationRuleCertification();

ViewData["CertificationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Certifications.ToList(), "CertificationId", "CertificationName");
ViewData["CertificationRuleId"] = new SelectList(_context.CertificationRules.ToList(), "CertificationRuleId", "RuleName");
```

Since you are using Razor, the code that I am suggesting should be placed not in `Create` page code, but in a  code behind the partial page. Use `OnGet` or `OnGetAsync` for this code.

But much better variant is to use a model to keep select lists. Just add two more properties `CertificationIdList` and `CertificationRuleIdList` to the existing model.

Comment: I tried editing OnGetCertificationPartial() to replace ViewData with ViewBag. Visual Studio now gives an error "the name ViewBag does not exist in the current context". Please note, I didn't need to do that for the OnGet method and that is working perfectly.

Comment: @MaxPowers Try to add using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; to your code behind. Or maybe Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor if you use razor

Comment: I updated the code to show the usings that are in place. That is not the issue, if it was why does OnGet work perfectly? Also, please note this is .NET Core 5.0 razor pages not MVC.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see any select  in Details.cshtml. How it could be working?

Comment: The only reason I included Details.chtml was to demonstrate where the click action that requests the modal form is originating from, beyond that it is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I still get the same result, empty dropdowns via OnGetCertificationPartial

Comment: @MaxPowers You are using Razor, not MVC. Your partial view has code behind. All the code that I am  suggesting should be not in Create page code, it should be in a partial view code.

Comment: OnGetCertificationPartial is the code behind the partial view, your suggestions does not solve the issue.

Comment: You have to put this code OnGet of your partial view

Comment: OnGet had no issue, it's already working without modification (it's what scaffolding generated)

Comment: You have to add  OnGet to code behind of  _CertificationRuleCertification.cshtml  and use this for the my code

Comment: What you are saying does not match up with any of the documentation about using partials. What does OnGet have to do with it? The partial routes through OnGetCertificationPartial. Maybe instead of describing what to do with the code you could demonstrate the change in the code.

Comment: Partial view in razor is called a partial page. And it doesn't have much difference from razor page. It works the same way.  What are you really using?